# #ifdef inside #define

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

I am trying to write something like this:

```
#define COV_ON(x) \
                #ifdef COVERAGE_TOOL \
                    _Pragma (COVERAGE #x)
                #endif
```

Is there any way to define `COV_ON` like this? I know what I have done above is wrong as I can't have `#ifdef` inside #define. (`#` is not an allowed character in `#define`). 
So is there any solution?

Comment: All of the answers here seem to omit the use of `do {} while(0)` (or equivalent) to avoid an empty statement; see the [my answer on the linked duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7246573/8446)

Answer (score 114, accepted):

Not possible.  Do it the other way around:

```
#ifdef COVERAGE_TOOL
#define COV_ON(x) _Pragma (COVERAGE #x)
#else
#define COV_ON(x)
#endif
```

Answer (score 23):

Simply turn it around:

```
#ifdef COVERAGE_TOOL
#define COV_ON(x) _Pragma (COVERAGE #x)
#else
#define COV_ON(x) /* foo */
#endif
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried COV_ON(on) and COV_ON(off) but then I get an error saying error:expected ')',near off. Any idea about the problem.

Comment: they are strings. Do i need to use them as regular strings inside quote? Like "on" and "off".

Comment: It depends on your definition of COVERAGE, but I'd guess that you need to quote them. I suggest that you open another question for this new issue.

Comment: I tried it with quotes but of no use. I have already opened a new thread. Let me know if you think syntax for _Pragma is wrong.

Answer (score 20):

This is an old question, but it needed an up to date answer.

Instead of using an inline ifdef within the macro you can selectively define a `__VA_ARGS__` macro to do the same thing

```
#ifdef COVERAGE_TOOL
#define IF_COVERAGE_TOOL(...) __VA_ARGS__
#else
#define IF_COVERAGE_TOOL(...)
#endif
#define COV_ON(x) IF_COVERAGE_TOOL( _Pragma (COVERAGE #x) )
```

This has similar functionality to an ifdef except that you get parentheses to delineate the beginning and end (which most IDEs have no problems code-folding)  While you can still use `#define` and `#ifdef` within the context, `#include` is not allowed.  In order to get inline capabilities similar to `#else`, you can define a corresponding macro like this:

```
//#define FOO
#ifdef FOO
#define IF_FOO(...) __VA_ARGS__ 
#define NO_FOO(...)
#else
#define IF_FOO(...)
#define NO_FOO(...) __VA_ARGS__
#endif

IF_FOO(
  #define BAR 5
  int foo = BAR;
)
NO_FOO(
  #define foo 5
)
```

Only one of `NO_FOO()/IF_FOO` will produce code.

OK, that's a handy hack, but can we make it *MORE* useful than `#ifdefs`... Boolean logic and configuration perhaps?  Lets set up some truth tables (and a couple helper macros).

```
#define PASTE_(x,y) x##y
#define PASTE(x,y) PASTE_(x,y)
#define PASTE3_(x,y,z) x##y##z
#define PASTE3(x,y,z) PASTE3_(x,y,z)
#define Y(...) __VA_ARGS__
#define N(...)
#define IF(x) x //alternate method similar to IFNOT()

#define NOT_N Y
#define NOT_Y N
#define IF_NOT(x) PASTE(NOT_,x)
#define NOT(x) PASTE(NOT_,x)

#define N_OR_N N
#define N_OR_Y Y
#define Y_OR_N Y
#define Y_OR_Y Y
#define OR(x,y) PASTE3(x,_OR_,y)

#define N_AND_N N
#define N_AND_Y N
#define Y_AND_N N
#define Y_AND_Y Y
#define AND(x,y) PASTE3(x,_AND_,y)

#define N_XOR_N N
#define N_XOR_Y Y
#define Y_XOR_N Y
#define Y_XOR_Y N
#define XOR(x,y) PASTE3(x,_XOR_,y)

#define N_NOR_N Y
#define N_NOR_Y N
#define Y_NOR_N N
#define Y_NOR_Y N
#define NOR(x,y) PASTE3(x,_NOR_,y)

#define N_NAND_N Y
#define N_NAND_Y Y
#define Y_NAND_N Y
#define Y_NAND_Y N
#define NAND(x,y) PASTE3(x,_NAND_,y)

#define N_XNOR_N Y
#define N_XNOR_Y N
#define Y_XNOR_N N
#define Y_XNOR_Y Y
#define XNOR(x,y) PASTE3(x,_XNOR_,y)

#define IF2(x,y,z) PASTE3(x,y,z)
```

config.h

```
#define FOO Y
#define BAR N
#define BAZ Y
```

code.c

```
AND(FOO,BAR)(/*do stuff if both FOO and BAR are enabled*/)
IF2(FOO,_AND_,BAR)( /*do stuff if both FOO and BAR are enabled*/ )
OR(BAZ,AND(FOO,BAR))(
  /*do stuff if both FOO and BAR are enabled or BAZ is enabled*/
)
```

Comment: I like your style (=

Answer (score 6):

```
#ifdef COVERAGE_TOOL
    #define COV_ON(x) _Pragma (COVERAGE #x)
#else
    #define COV_ON(x)
#endif
```

Answer (score 6):

You cannot. But you can swap `#ifdef` and `#define`:

```
#ifdef COVERAGE_TOOL
#   define COV_ON(x) _Pragma (COVERAGE #x)
#else
#   define COV_ON(x)
#endif
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried COV_ON(on) and COV_ON(off) but then I get an error saying error:expected ')',near off. Any idea about the problem.

Comment: Without knowing your compiler, we would need to know what the expected `_Pragma` syntax is; how would you do it without a macro?

Comment: I m using VC2005 compiler and saw _Pragma syntax online. I never used #pragma in this way before.

Comment: You will need a stringify hack, then. See [this question and answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3030099/c-c-pragma-in-define-macro/3030312#3030312).

Comment: I guess the problem is VC2005. They dont use _Pragma but use __pragma. I am not sure but it looks like that. But still I am getting a warning unknown pragma with __pragma.

Answer (score 3):

As you mentioned it is not possible to have an #ifdef in a #define.  What you should do instead is reverse the order:

```
#ifdef COVERAGE_TOOL \
  #define COV_ON(x) \
    etc.
#endif
```