# "#ifdef" inside a macro

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [#ifdef inside #define](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5586429/ifdef-inside-define)

How do I use the character "#" successfully inside a Macro? It screams when I do something like that:

```
#define DO(WHAT)        \
#ifdef DEBUG        \                           
  MyObj->WHAT()         \       
#endif              \
```

Answer (score 72, accepted):

You can't do that. You have to do something like this:

```
#ifdef DEBUG
#define DO(WHAT) MyObj->WHAT()
#else
#define DO(WHAT) do { } while(0)
#endif
```

The `do { } while(0)` avoids empty statements. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/923822/whats-the-use-of-do-while0-when-we-define-a-macro), for example.

Comment: So with an empty statement I could run into trouble on some c++ compilers? My app is cross platform, OSX, Windows and Ubuntu. Is this the safe thing to do?

Comment: +1: The `do {} while(0)` construct is something I forgot to mention in my answer.

Comment: @Ron: This actually lets you write : `if(x) DO(m); else DO(n);`.  while @Oli's solution will give compilation error.

Comment: This is one reason to use inline functions rather than macros!

Comment: @Bo Persson: What solution do you suggest using inline functions? Please post.

Comment: DO(m) and DO(n) can easily be function calls. Why bother with tricky macros?

Comment: Well, in this case, `MyObj` would have to be passed as an argument to those functions, so it's not a drop in replacement. Moreover, you'd then have to mess about with pointer-to-member parameters, which could get ugly quite quickly. That said, I don't actually like this use of macros to hide what's going on, but the question was asked...

Comment: what about simply `#define DO(WHAT) ;` in the #else branch?

Answer (score 13):

It screams because you can't do that.

I suggest the following as an alternative:

```
#ifdef DEBUG
#define DO(WHAT) MyObj->WHAT()
#else
#define DO(WHAT)
#endif
```

Answer (score 5):

It seems that what you want to do can be achieved like this, without running into any problems:

```
#ifdef DEBUG
#    define DO(WHAT) MyObj->WHAT()
#else
#    define DO(WHAT) while(false)
#endif
```

Btw, better use the `NDEBUG` macro, unless you have a more specific reason not to. `NDEBUG` is more widely used as a macro that means no-debugging. For example the standard [`assert`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cassert/assert/) macro can be disabled by defining `NDEBUG`. Your code would become:

```
#ifndef NDEBUG
#    define DO(WHAT) MyObj->WHAT()
#else
#    define DO(WHAT) while(false)
#endif
```

Comment: You should emphasize that since `NDEBUG` means no-debugging, the `#ifdef` becomes `#ifndef`.

Answer (score 2):

You can do the same thing like this:

```
#ifdef DEBUG
#define DO(WHAT) MyObj->WHAT()
#else
#define DO(WHAT)
#endif
```

Comment: See other for correct way to avoid empty statements...

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
#ifdef DEBUG
#define DO(WHAT) MyObj->WHAT()
#else
#define DO(WHAT)
#endif
```