# Ways to wrap some lines of code into a single macro

Tags: c++, c, macros

I have the following lines of code which is needed to be written across many files in a project:-

```
#if SOME_CHECK
    foo(x, y, z);
#endif
```

For this, I am planning to wrap the above 3 lines of code into a single macro like this-

```
#define foo(x, y, z) #if SOME_CHECK \
foo(x, y, z); \
#endif
```

But, this is giving me error for obvious reasons and I am unable to think of a better way to make use of the preprocessor macros to wrap those 3 lines of code. Can anyone suggest some better ways to handle the above problem?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5586429/ifdef-inside-define

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The classic way to do this would be:

#### foo.h

```
#ifndef FOO_H_INCLUDED
#define FOO_H_INCLUDED

#if SOME_CHECK
extern void foo(int x, int y, int z);
#define FOO(x, y, z) foo(x, y, z)
#else
#define FOO(x, y, z) ((void)0)
#endif

#endif /* FOO_H_INCLUDED */
```

#### Code conditionally calling `foo()`

```
#include "foo.h"

...
FOO(a, b, c);
...
```

When SOME_CHECK is defined to a non-zero value, then the code will call `foo()` with the given arguments.  When SOME_CHECK is not defined, the code will expand to `((void)0)` which will be ignored by the compiler.

You probably can leave the alternative definition as an empty string if you wish (instead of using `((void)0)`, but you'd run into problems if someone tried to use `FOO()` in the context of a comma operator, or a ternary operator, for example:

```
FOO(a, b, c), ALTEREGO(d, e f);

(x > y) ? FOO(a, b, c) : ALTEREGO(d, e, f);
```

In both of those, `#define FOO(x, y, z) /* Nothing */` would generate syntax errors.  This is not the end of the world; they're both horrid bits of code and shouldn't be encouraged.  But that's a judgement call you'll have to make for your project.

Answer (score 3):

Why not do this?

```
#if SOME_CHECK
... The actual function
#else
    #define foo(x,y,z)
#endif
```

Whereby any occurrence of `foo` will be zapped then `SOME_CHECK` is set. Otherwise the function is called.

Comment: Note that this solution comes with small side effects. You might get warnings about x, y and z not i use

Comment: @JonathanLeffler - Corrected - Opps. -eyalm - Depends on the compiler and warning levels. If using C++ could use inline functions instead

Answer (score 0):

how about trying:

```
#ifdef SOME_CHECK
#define foo(x,y,z) foo(x,y,z);
#else
#define foo(x,y,z)
#endif
```