# Disabling warning elegantly

Tags: c++, macros

I have a class that is exported and it uses a header only structure as a member variable.

```
#include "SomeStruct.h"

class API_CLASS SomeClass
{
public:
// ...
private:
#pragma warning( push )
#pragma warning( disable: 4251 )
    SomeStruct _active;
#pragma warning( pop )
};
```

I get warning 4251 as the structure is not exported. The structure is part of an external code and not a part of current scope.

I would like to make this code a bit more readable as this is a header I will distribute.
Ideally, I want the class to read

```
#include "SomeStruct.h"

class API_CLASS SomeClass
{
public:
// ...
private:
DISABLE_WARNING_BEGIN(4251)
    SomeStruct _active;
DISABLE_WARNING_END
};
```

It may be more work to disable multiple warnings but if that can be done, then great but not necessary. The macro should result in code only for WIN32 environment. I have tried to write the macro but to include a '#' is beyond me.

Comment: To be honest I wouldn't go there... The warning numbers are compiler-specific anyway, so you'd be obscuring rather than clarifying. For ignoring a warning for the following line only, you can use the more compact "#pragma warning(suppress: 4251)".

Answer (score 0):

I can live with this. This is better than what I have now.

```
#include "SomeStruct.h"

class API_CLASS SomeClass
{
public:
// ...
private:
#pragma warning(suppress: 4251)
    SomeStruct _active;
};
```

Thanks to Heinirichj

Answer (score 0):

To add `#pragma` into a MACRO, you may use:

- `__pragma` with MSVC
- `_Pragma` with gcc

See [Pragma in define macro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3030099/c-c-pragma-in-define-macro) for more detail.