# What is __pragma and what are the differences between __pragma and #pragma

Tags: c++, macros

The following macros confused me. I wondering what is __pragma and wwhat are the differences between __pragma and #pragma.

```
#define OPENVDB_START_THREADSAFE_STATIC_WRITE       __pragma(warning(disable:1711))
#define OPENVDB_FINISH_THREADSAFE_STATIC_WRITE      __pragma(warning(default:1711))
```

Comment: `The __pragma keyword, which is specific to the Microsoft compiler, enables you to code pragma directives within macro definitions.` (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d9x1s805.aspx)

Answer (score 15):

`#pragma` is a preprocessor directive in its own right; it can't be used within a `#define` directive.

So, this is why `__pragma` exists: it provides a way for a pragma to be issued from wherever the macro that uses it is expanded.

This is a non-standard compiler extension (MSVC, Intel, and some C compilers support it to varying degrees). See also the [`_Pragma` operator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3030312/21475) that is defined in newer versions of the C/C++ standards (and serves the same purpose, but with a slightly different syntax).

Comment: Standard C, as of the 1999 standard (which Microsoft doesn't support) has a `_Pragma` operator, which is probably similar to Microsoft's `__pragma`.