# How to eliminate the C4003 warning when executing the traditional C preprocessor with the /EP switch?

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++, visual-studio-2019, c-preprocessor

MSVC uses the traditional preprocessor [**by default**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/preprocessor-experimental-overview?view=msvc-170).

When this preprocessor is executed with the [**`/EP`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/ep-preprocess-to-stdout-without-hash-line-directives?view=msvc-160) command line [**switch**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/ep-preprocess-to-stdout-without-hash-line-directives?view=msvc-160) and it invokes the following concatenating macro `CONCAT(aa,bb,cc)`, it generates the correct output:

> aabbcc

... but it also generates this undesirable warning:

> Warning C4003: not enough arguments for function-like macro invocation 'CONCAT'

See the [**online simulation here**](https://godbolt.org/z/dr469aaEj).

The `CONCAT()` macro is defined below ( it can be invoked with an arbitrary number of arguments ):

```
#if !defined(_MSVC_TRADITIONAL) || _MSVC_TRADITIONAL

#pragma warning( push )
#pragma warning( disable : 4003 )
#define CONCAT_(A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P,Q,R,S,T,U,V,W,X,Y,Z) A##B##C##D##E##F##G##H##I##J##K##L##M##N##O##P##Q##R##S##T##U##V##W##X##Y##Z
#define CONCAT(A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P,Q,R,S,T,U,V,W,X,Y,Z) CONCAT_(A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P,Q,R,S,T,U,V,W,X,Y,Z)
#pragma warning( pop )

#else

#define CONCAT_EVAL1(...) __VA_ARGS__
#define CONCAT_EVAL2(...) CONCAT_EVAL1(CONCAT_EVAL1(CONCAT_EVAL1(CONCAT_EVAL1(__VA_ARGS__))))
#define CONCAT_EVAL3(...) CONCAT_EVAL2(CONCAT_EVAL2(CONCAT_EVAL2(CONCAT_EVAL2(__VA_ARGS__))))
#define CONCAT_EVAL4(...) CONCAT_EVAL3(CONCAT_EVAL3(CONCAT_EVAL3(CONCAT_EVAL3(__VA_ARGS__))))
#define CONCAT_EVAL5(...) CONCAT_EVAL4(CONCAT_EVAL4(CONCAT_EVAL4(CONCAT_EVAL4(__VA_ARGS__))))

#define CONCAT_EMPTY()

#define CONCAT_TUPLE_AT_1(a,b,...) b
#define CONCAT_CHECK(...) CONCAT_TUPLE_AT_1(__VA_ARGS__)
#define CONCAT_PROBE(...) ,CONCAT_END,

#define CONCAT_IND() CONCAT_
#define CONCAT_(x,a,...) CONCAT_CHECK(CONCAT_PROBE a,CONCAT_NEXT)(x,a,__VA_ARGS__)
#define CONCAT_NEXT(x,a,...) CONCAT_IND CONCAT_EMPTY()()(x##a,__VA_ARGS__)
#define CONCAT_END(x,a,...) x

#define CONCAT(...) CONCAT_EVAL5(CONCAT_(,__VA_ARGS__,()))

#endif
```

Of course, when the standard conforming preprocessor is invoked with the `/Zc:preprocessor` command line switch, then the condition `#if !defined(_MSVC_TRADITIONAL) || _MSVC_TRADITIONAL` fails and the offending code is not expanded and the warning C4003 is not generated.

Notice, that if the [**`/EP`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/ep-preprocess-to-stdout-without-hash-line-directives?view=msvc-160) switch is **not** in effect, then the warning C4003 can be disabled for the macro invocation with `#pragma warning( disable : 4003 )`. 
See this [**online simulation**](https://godbolt.org/z/18YPPnKq5).
...but as soon as you add the [**`/EP`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/ep-preprocess-to-stdout-without-hash-line-directives?view=msvc-160) switch to the compiler's options, this warning reappears!

**QUESTION**:  How to disable this warning in the traditional preprocessor for just this concatenating macro when the [`/EP`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/ep-preprocess-to-stdout-without-hash-line-directives?view=msvc-160) switch is in effect ...or how to alter this macro so it does not generate that warning with the traditional preprocessor and the [`/EP`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/ep-preprocess-to-stdout-without-hash-line-directives?view=msvc-160) switch ?

NOTE: 
*Please do not suggest using the global switch `/wd"4003"` to disable this warning everywhere, because this warning is needed to check other macros in other code.*

Answer (score -1):

[C4003 question](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/5fbb38e4-4994-4a83-9048-8e70bfd31b85/turning-warning-c4003-into-an-error-for-a-particular-macro-invocation?forum=vclanguage) was mentioned a long time ago. The experimental preprocessor also treats it as an error.

> there is no way to tell VC not to issue a  warning when pasing empty
> arguments to macro parameters, short of  suppressing C4003 warning
> altogether, in all cases.

Comment: But the preprocessor does **not** treat fewer macro arguments as an error - it treats it as a warning.   I have a problem that I cannot disable this warning with anything else but a global switch when the `/EP` switch is in effect.  The 11 year old discussion, which you had linked to, was discussing the inability to turn this warning into an error - a different issue ...albeit related.

Comment: According to the [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54250808/how-to-disable-a-warning-within-a-c-macro), warning 4307 can be disabled, but 4003 not work. You can report the problem to [Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/cpp)`#define TIMES_A_MILLION(x,b) \
__pragma (warning(suppress: 4003)) \
__pragma (warning(suppress: 4307)) \
  x * 1000000`

Comment: I am afraid of the `Developer Community`.  It is full of MSFTs...