# How can #pragma be portablized?

Tags: c++, porting, pragma

Is it possible to portablize all `#pragma` commands? `#pragma once` can be portablize as the following:

```
#ifndef FOO
#define FOO
//Code here
#endif
```

However, I am not aware of universal implementations for `#pragma pack` and others. Is this possible?

Comment: Everything can be portablized. The effort required for some might be on par with writing a new programming language, though.

Comment: Some C or C++ compilers can be customized with plugins, which can add additional pragmas. But by definition pragmas are implementation specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The specification of pragmas in the standard is essentially an implementation-defined hook - the results of every pragma is implementation-defined.    The results can include causing translation to fail, the implementation or emitted code behaving in a non-conforming manner (i.e. do things with any code construct differently than the standard requires).    Implementations are required to ignore pragmas they don't recognise.

By definition, therefore, there are no universal definitions.   There is also nothing preventing two different compilers from doing completely different things with the same pragma.

To "portabilize" such things, it is necessary to have a consistent specification of the features and behaviours that compiler vendors can implement (and, then, that programmers can consistently use).   Getting such a specification is challenging but not impossible.  Firstly, a specification needs to be shared - formally (e.g. in a standard) or informally (e.g. a specification agreed between some vendors, even if it is not actually in a standard).  Second, it requires requires all vendors to agree to implement it - which is not a given, even if it is in a ratified standard.    Third, it requires any  variations between implementations to be understood, and accepted by developers (or, at the least, a reasonable majority).

When agreement is required between multiple players (vendors, developers, committees, the list goes on) it takes more effort to get agreement.  With C++, there is no body that has sufficient "pull" to guarantee that some feature will be successfully "portabilized" - or, to put it another way, there is nobody with a trump vote who can be convinced to make something universal.   Getting 100% "portabilization" will be hard - practically, there will often be a "near enough" result rather than 100%.

Answer (score 1):

No, pragma implementations are left up to the preprocessor or compiler author and are not specified in the C++ Standard.

See https://isocpp.org/std/the-standard.

It's easier to read than one might expect.

What you posted will not result in precisely the same behavior. #pragma once in VS does not equate to the inclusion guard #ifdef you wrote.

Comment: "easier to read that[sic] one might expect".  from the link: " FAQs
Q: Why is the standard hard to read?...", heh

Comment: Not all pragmas are for preprocessor. For example, `#pragma omp` (and `_Pragma(omp...)` form - http://stackoverflow.com/a/3030312) are for compiler.

Comment: @osgx Thank you.