# macro definition containing #pragma

Tags: c++, macros

I am trying to define the following macro:

```
#if defined(_MSC_VER)
    #define PRAGMA_PACK_PUSH(n)  __pragma(pack(push, n))
    #define PRAGMA_PACK_POP()    __pragma(pack(pop))
#else
    #define PRAGMA_PACK_PUSH(n)     #pragma (pack(push, n))
    #define PRAGMA_PACK_POP()       #pragma (pack(pop))
#endif
```

But i get the following error on Linux -

```
 error: '#' is not followed by a macro parameter
  #define PRAGMA_PACK_PUSH(n)  #pragma (pack(push, n))
```

and it points to the first ')' in the statment

How can i define a macro that contains a #?

Solution Update:

As stated in this thread [Pragma in define macro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3030099/pragma-in-define-macro/3030312#3030312) the syntax that worked is:

```
#if defined(_MSC_VER)
    #define PRAGMA_PACK_PUSH(n)  __pragma(pack(push, n))
    #define PRAGMA_PACK_POP()    __pragma(pack(pop))
#else
    #define PRAGMA_PACK_PUSH(n)     _Pragma("pack(push, n)")
    #define PRAGMA_PACK_POP()       _Pragma("pack(pop)")
#endif
```

Comment: VS can handle `#pragma` syntax just fine, why do you use `__pragma` one? Just use `#pragma` everywhere.

Comment: @VTT Not inside a define!

Comment: @aschepler There is no point in defining this macro if in both cases `#pragma` syntax woks.

Comment: @VTT the defines are here because it's a pain to write _pragma(pack(push, n)) or __pragma(pack(pop)) over and over again. It's used for shortcut purposes

Comment: @darkThoughts These macros are shorter only by 6 symbols, it doesn't seem to save that much, if any, considering that you will need to #include header where these macros are defined.

Answer (score 7):

> How can i define a macro that contains a #?

You can't (define a macro that contains a directive, that is. # can still be used in macros for stringization and as ## for token concatenation). That's why `_Pragma` was invented and standardized in C99. As for C++, it's definitely in the C++11 standard and presumably the later ones.

You can use it as follows:

```
#define PRAGMA(X) _Pragma(#X)
#define PRAGMA_PACK_PUSH(n)     PRAGMA(pack(push,n))
#define PRAGMA_PACK_POP()       PRAGMA(pack(pop))
```

With that,

```
PRAGMA_PACK_PUSH(1)
struct x{
    int i;
    double d;
};
PRAGMA_PACK_POP()
```

preprocesses to

```
# 10 "pack.c"
#pragma pack(push,1)
# 10 "pack.c"

struct x{
 int i;
 double d;
};

# 15 "pack.c"
#pragma pack(pop)
# 15 "pack.c"
```

As you can see, the `_Pragma`s are expanding to `#pragma` directives.
Since `_Pragma` is standard, you should be able to avoid the `#ifdef` here if Microsoft supports it.

Comment: VS throws the error "this declaration has no storage class or type specifier" when using the proposed syntax. I have found a solution and will update my post accordingly

Comment: @darkThoughts With your solution, the `n` argument will be just the letter `n`. Its value won't get interpolated into the `pragma`.

Comment: So at least in Linux where it's supported i should use your solution?

Comment: @darkThoughts My solution should work on every standard-compliant compiler. It definitely does work on gcc/linux and clang/linux.