# How to #import inside a #define

Tags: c++, objective-c, xcode, c-preprocessor

I'm working on an Objective-C wrapper around a C++ library, whose source I neither control nor modify. The headers I import trigger various compiler warnings, so I've started to do the following:

```
#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wreserved-id-macro"
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wstrict-prototypes"
#import "dll.hpp"
#pragma clang diagnostic pop
```

This works great, but to keep it [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself), I'd like to define a macro for each of these imports with the ignored warning pragmas built in (there are only a few headers like this).

This way, in each file I could just make a call like this at the top and I'd have the ignored warnings all in one spot for each header.

```
ImportDllHpp()
```

It's not so easy, however, calling `#import` from within a `#define`. I've gotten pretty close, using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3030312/105717) to get the pragmas working. But is there a function like `_Pragma` for `#import` or another way to achieve that?

This is what I have so far:

```
#define _stringify(a) #a

#define ImportRarHpp() \
_Pragma( _stringify( clang diagnostic push ) ) \
_Pragma( _stringify( clang diagnostic ignored "-Wreserved-id-macro" ) ) \
_Pragma( _stringify( clang diagnostic ignored "-Wstrict-prototypes" ) ) \
#import "dll.hpp"
_Pragma( _stringify( clang diagnostic pop ) )
```

Answer (score 2):

I would be very surprised if you could do this.

I would suggest the simplest solution is for you to simply define your own file named something like `my-dll.hpp` which consists of

```
#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wreserved-id-macro"
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wstrict-prototypes"
#import "dll.hpp"
#pragma clang diagnostic pop
```

That way anyone who wants to import `dll.hpp` will instead just `#import "my-dll.hpp"` and the appropriate warnings will be suppressed.

Comment: I was thinking of `#include "my-dll.hpp"` instead (I'm not up on C++17 yet), but same concept.  Move the `#pragma`s and `#import` to its own file, then include/import that flle where needed