# Can GCC be configured to ignore #pragma directives?

Tags: c++, gcc, pragma

We are compiling and running user submitted C++ programs in a sandbox environment with the following compile command:

```
g++ -std=gnu++11 -O2 -o program.exe program.cpp
```

However, it is possible for users to override compile flags using pragma directives. For example, the optimisation level can be overridden with this code:

```
#pragma GCC optimize("Ofast")
```

We have no control over the source code which is submitted for compilation but we need to prevent compile options from being overridden.

Is there a way to ignore pragma directives with GCC?

Comment: Why can't you process the source before compilation?

Comment: @hyde: Probably harder than it seems, especially given the C99/C++11 `_Pragma` operator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From a quick scan of the man page, the answer is "No", `gcc` has no "disable pragmas" feature.

As a truly ridiculous workaround, you might simple require all entries to omit the string `pragma` (case-insensitive to block [the `_Pragma` operator](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3030099/364696) as well) entirely, rejecting any that violate that requirement. Anything more complicated that that will essentially entail writing your own C source code parser, and I doubt it's worth the trouble. Not really sure even that will work, given the token concatenation tricks you can play with the preprocessor (I await a comment demonstrating such an exploit).

Comment: Preprosessor tricks should be easy to avoid by first running preprosessor, then filtering/checking the preprosessor output (C code) before compilation.

Comment: @hyde: True. Depends how flexible their submission system is (it didn't sound very flexible from their question, e.g. they claimed they couldn't control the source code *at all*).